# C return number of duplicate characters

Tags: c, arrays, string

I was doing a coding challenge on codewars.com and the challenge was to take a string as input, check it for duplicate characters and return the number of duplicate characters. It can be assumed that all characters will be letters only.

So anyways I got my code working and submitted it, afterwards I saw this code on the same problem in the number 1 spot, codewars.com lets you see how other people solved the problem too.

Here it is

```
size_t duplicate_count(const char* text)
{
    char seen[127] = { 0 };
    size_t duplicates = 0;
    char c;

    while ((c = *text++))
    {
        if (seen[tolower(c)]++ == 1) duplicates++;
    }

    return duplicates;
}
```

Theres a few things that I don't understand about this code, although I'm sure it's pretty simple.

1) Why use 127 as the size of the seen char array? There are 26 letters in the alphabet, and this person is already casting the characters to lowercase in the while loop, so I wouldn't think you would have to worry about it being uppercase anyways.

2) this line

```
if (seen[tolower(c)]++ == 1) duplicates++;
```

I get that it is checking to see if the current character in the string is in the seen array, but how? The syntax isn't making sense to me is what I'm saying.

Thank you all for your time. I was going to post this on code review instead, but I have been told that it's not really a "how to" site.

Comment: What exactly was the task to count? What should be returned for `"AAA"`?

Comment: I think this question is too broad. Especially if you've never seen an `if` statement before, you should probably read an introduction to C first.

Comment: @melpomene Ive seen an if statement before, I was just asking about the rest of the line.

Comment: @alk It is supposed to only count 1 duplicate for each letter. So for "AAA" it would only return 1, because the letter a is the only duplicate. The string "AABBCC" would return 3 duplicates. The case of the letters are ignored using the tolower() function.

Comment: No, you asked about the whole thing, which is an `if` statement. Please be specific: What exactly is unclear to you? Do you know what `++` does? Do you know how variables work? Function calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Why use 127 as the size of the seen char array?

No clear idea. `char` might be signed or unsigned. In the case of signed characters, the highest value (assuming 8 bit characters) can be 127. In this case, the array should be `seen[128]`.
The [ASCII 127 → Delete character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character) might be considered as special and hence is not expected to occur...

> 2)

The line:

```
if (seen[tolower(c)]++ == 1) duplicates++;
```

could also be written as:

```
char cLower = tolower(c);
int seenOld = seen[cLower];
++seen[cLower];
if (seenOld == 1) ++duplicates;
```

It exploits the effect of post-increment which returns old value and applies its effect (increment) afterwards.

In the case of `duplicates++`, the returned old value is unused.
Hence, the effect of `++duplicates` vs. `duplicates++` is neglectable.